# z-index property changed on click using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery code to show/hide DIV's depending on what div is clicked on. This works fine...

but my divs are right on the top of each other and when the top ones are clicked, they will display under the bottom ones! I can change the z-index using CSS but When i do that, the bottom ones are not clickable anymore!

so i thought about getting jQuery to bring the DIV's to the front and when they are not visible, then change the z-index back!

is this possible?

here is my jQuery code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".toggle").next(".hidden").hide();
    $(this).parent().css('height', '10%');
    jQuery(".toggle").click(function() {

        $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
        $(this).parent().css('z-index', 999999999);
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");

    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="off1" class="offers">
   <div class="toggle" style="width:100%; height:50px; background-color:#f8134a; padding:5px;">
      <div  style=" cursor:pointer; border:dashed 2px #FFF; width:90%; height:30px; margin-left:-5px; margin-top:5px; background-image:url(images/doublehearts.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%; font-family:'Arno Pro'; font-size:22px; color:#FFF; padding-top:5px; text-transform:uppercase;">FLOWERS</div>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden" style=" display:none; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#FFF;"></div>
</div>
<div id="off2" class="offers2">
   <div class="toggle" style=" width:100%; height:50px; background-color:#f8134a; padding:5px;">
      <div style=" cursor:pointer; border:dashed 2px #FFF; width:90%; height:30px; margin-left:-5px; margin-top:5px; background-image:url(images/doublehearts.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%; font-family:'Arno Pro'; font-size:22px; color:#FFF; padding-top:5px; text-transform:uppercase;">RESTAURANTS</div>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden" style=" display:none; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#FFF;"></div>
</div>
<div id="off3" class="offers3">
   <div class="toggle" style="width:100%; height:50px; background-color:#f8134a; padding:5px;">
      <div  style=" cursor:pointer; border:dashed 2px #FFF; width:90%; height:30px; margin-left:-5px; margin-top:5px; background-image:url(images/doublehearts.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%; font-family:'Arno Pro'; font-size:22px; color:#FFF; padding-top:5px; text-transform:uppercase;">Sweets & Chocolate</div>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden" style=" display:none; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#FFF;"></div>
</div>
```

AND HERE IS THE CSS:

```
.offers{
  z-index:999;
  position: absolute;
  width:30%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 18%;
  right: 0;
  float:left;
  top: 10%;
  padding:2px;
}



.offers2{
   z-index:999;
   position: absolute;
   width:30%;
   height: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
   left: 52%;
   right: 0;
   float:left;
   top: 10%;
   padding:2px;
}

.offers3{
  z-index:9999;
  position: absolute;
  width:30%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 18%;
  right: 0;
  float:left;
  top: 20%;
  padding:2px;
}
```

Comment: you should just add a class to the element that needs to be displayed. In your css you can give this class a z-index value. So every time you click, you just need to remove that class from all the elements and add it to the one you clicked

Comment: @Huangism, the elements already have their classes. but as i said, they are placed on the top of each other!

Comment: please show your html as it is confusing to me what's wrong with your code. If you have your divs on top of each other and the only way to activate one is to click on it, then it seems to me there is no way to activate more than 1 div since you set the active one to a high z-index covering the rest of the divs

Comment: @Huangism, please view the updated question.

Comment: How would you click those in the background if they all cover each other anyway? Can you show us a fiddle or something?

Comment: @helion3, I click on the `.toggle` and it shows the `.hidden`... all the code for it to work is in my question.

Comment: Having the code is great but we're not computers and don't parse the code. Having a demo/jiddle/codepen allows us to see what you mean, see what's broken, inspect it, and possibly fix it

Comment: is the issue that when the hidden is shown, it covers up other divs?

Comment: @helion3, there is nothing to fix! everything works as it should. just need to change the z-index using jquery as explained in my question! also, I did put my code in jsfiddle but it doesn't run properly in jsfiddle but it does in my HTML file!

Comment: @Huangism, no, it covers the bottom ones even if they are not shown! and that makes the bottom ones un-clickable!

Comment: If there's nothing to fix, why are you here? If you need to change the z-index through jQuery, then do it. Having elements constantly fighting to be seen because of z-index issues sounds ineffcient to me

Comment: @helion3, whats your problem? I'm here because i want to... none of your business....

Comment: @user3275767 well technically by posting here you make it everyone's business. You can put this in a fiddle and just link it here whether it works or not. This way others can fix your fiddle to the point where it works

Comment: @Huangism, yes, and same goes the other way... he has no right to ask me or anyone "what are you doing here".. especially when this is a community run website!!

Comment: @user3275767 I think he is trying to point out the fact that in your code, you have already edited the z-index with code, so what's stopping you to edit it again

Comment: @user3275767 You're asking for help on a community website and you began by attacking. QUOTE: "there is nothing to fix! everything works as it should", and we're simply trying to help. If you want to be rude, then you don't deserve to continue here.

Comment: @user3275767 I have included a fiddle in the updated answer. You probably did not include jquery library on fiddle so it did not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert the z-index thing then just set it back to 999 or leave it as blank so the inline z-index css is gone

http://jsfiddle.net/nYjLV/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle").next(".hidden").hide();
    $(this).parent().css('height', '10%');
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.parent().css('z-index', 999);
            $this.removeClass('active').next('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
        } else {
            $('.active').parent().css('z-index', 999);
            $('.active').removeClass('active').next('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
            $this.parent().css('z-index', 999999999);
            $this.addClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
$this.parent().css('z-index', '');
```

This removes the z-index so it uses the one you defined in the css

For your CSS, I would group all the common items into the class offers. Change all the classes to offers instead of offers 1/2/3

```
.offers {
    // common attributes
}

#off1 {
    // differences like left and top attribute
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nYjLV/4/ css/html updated